# NumberFormat Exception in Android

Tags: android

This is my calculator app, I know that NumberFormat are caused when we try convert string to numerical type.I have also surrounded them by TRY/CATCH but i cant seem to get them as INT values. Here in my app, I'm getting the strings in the textview and trying to perform operations on them.

Can anyone suggest an alternative approach for the problem?

Here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static String GAT = "Tag";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    String stringOne = " ";
    String stringTwo = " ";

    public void onClick1(View view) {
        //Getting Input from TextView
        TextView inputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputTextView);
        Button button = (Button) view;

        //Store as String from button press
        stringOne = (String) button.getText().toString();
        Log.d(TAG, stringOne);
        //For entering multiple values
        if (!stringOne.contains("+") && !stringOne.contains("-") && !stringOne.contains("/") && !stringOne.contains("*")) {
            //Concat if it has multiple digits to original string
            stringTwo = stringTwo + stringOne;
            Log.d(TAG, stringTwo);
            //Remove the last string and place as StringTwo
            if (arrayList.size() > 0) {
                //Get last position in the array
                arrayList.remove((arrayList.size() - 1));

            }
            arrayList.add(stringTwo);
        } else {
            //For operators add two times because we removed the previous index
            arrayList.add(stringOne);
            arrayList.add(stringOne);
            //Clear
            stringTwo = " ";

            Toast.makeText(this, stringOne, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(TAG, stringOne);

            // Log.d("Veer",stringTwo);


        }

        //Add to TextView
        inputText.setText(inputText.getText().toString()+stringOne);
        //inputText.setText(arrayList.toString());
    }


    public void calculate(View view) {
        TextView outputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputTextView);
        int result = 0;
        int list = arrayList.size();

        while (list != 1) {
            if (list > 3) {
                //Considering the equation to be like 4+5*5-2/4, Get the third operator, if * and /, then multiply
                if (arrayList.get(3).contains("*") || arrayList.get(3).contains("/")) {
                    if (arrayList.get(3).contains("*")) {
                        result = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2)) * Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(4));
                    } else if (arrayList.get(3).contains("/")) {

                        result = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2)) / Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(4));
                    }
                    arrayList.remove(2);
                    arrayList.remove(2);
                    arrayList.remove(2);
                    arrayList.add(2, Integer.toString(result));
                    list = arrayList.size();
                } else {
                    //Vice versa, here for + and - ,replace 1st and 2nd digit
                    if (arrayList.get(1).contains("+")) {

                        result = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) + Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));
                    }
                    if (arrayList.get(1).contains("-")) {

                        result = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) - Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));
                    }
                    if (arrayList.get(1).contains("*")) {

                        result = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) * Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));
                    }
                    if (arrayList.get(1).contains("/")) {

                        result = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) / Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));
                    }
                    arrayList.remove(0);
                    arrayList.remove(0);
                    arrayList.remove(0);
                    arrayList.add(0, Integer.toString(result));
                    list = arrayList.size();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //If size is 3
                if (arrayList.get(1).contains("+")) {

                    result = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) + Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));
                }
                if (arrayList.get(1).contains("-")) {

                    result = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) - Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));
                }
                if (arrayList.get(1).contains("*")) {

                    result = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) * Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));
                }
                if (arrayList.get(1).contains("/")) {

                    result = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) / Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));
                }
                arrayList.remove(0);
                arrayList.remove(0);
                arrayList.remove(0);
                arrayList.add(0, Integer.toString(result));
                list = arrayList.size();
            }
        }
        outputText.setText(Integer.toString(result));
    }


    public void clearView(View view) {
        TextView input = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.inputTextView);
        TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputTextView);
        stringOne = "";
        stringTwo = "";
        input.setText("");
        output.setText("");
        arrayList.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: when you are getting error? why you dot try double instead of int ?

Comment: i'm getting runtime error depending upon the equation, if its 2*3 then i get an error on   if (arrayList.get(1).contains("*")) {

                    result = Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(0)) * Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(2));

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch exception whenever you convert string to numerical type. If it throw an exception then you return. And if no exception, you continue to perform operations on them.

```
    String text = "";
    int num;
    try {
       num = Integer.parseInt(text);
       // text is a number");
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Can not parse string to int: " + text,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       // text is not a number";
       // Show Log or make a Toast here to easy see when String is not Int format. After that find the reason why text is not int format
    }
```

Hope this help

Comment: ok, will not crash now, but how do i get them as INT

Comment: Of cource, If your input `STRING` data is right, you can parse it to `INT`. Therefore,  if you can not get value as `INT` your `STRING` is not INT format

Comment: what do you mean by input string data is right?

Comment: like if your String input is "2" you can parse it to int but the input string is "2 " or "a" or " 2", you will get error

Comment: i think i'm giving the correct input, can you verify please?

Comment: can anyone help me out here

Comment: @bappibazzi I have add a `toast` to my code, could you try it in your code then give my some clues

Comment: Can not parse string to int:0, because result is 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91045/discussion-between-phan-vn-linh-and-bappi-bazzi).

Comment: in my textview, i give input such as 3*5, and this calls the calculate() function and goes in the else code,i'm having problem parsing it from there

Answer (score 0):

```
 float num1 = 0;
 float num2 = 0;
 float result = 0;

 num1 = Float.parseFloat(etNum1.getText().toString());
 num2 = Float.parseFloat(etNum2.getText().toString());

result = num1 * num2 ;
Log.e("Result",""+result);
```

Hope it helps.